# How to display an imported image for a brief period of time?

Tags: java, image

I have imported an image (GIF) to display as part of an animation, and the GIF pops up fine. It, however, remains for the duration of the animation; I'm looking to have it appear for only a few seconds.

With a timer set in another method (elapsedTimeMsec), I have tried displaying the image if timer >= 5200 (5.2s) and timer < 6100 (6.1s).
While this same format (seen in code below) worked for Strings popping up, it does not seem to work for the imported image.

```
private static void imageImport (Graphics2D g, int elapsedTimeMsec)
    {
        if (elapsedTimeMsec >= 5200 && elapsedTimeMsec < 6100);
        {
            Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\mogen\\Pictures\\importImage\\explosion.gif");
            g.drawImage(image, 750, 425, null);
        }
}
```

I'm expecting the image to display within the time periods of 5.2s and 6.1s of the animation running; instead the image displays from the moment the animation starts indefinitely.

Comment: Are you using any user interface libary like `JavaFX`, `Swing`, `SWT` etc?

Comment: I think you need to delete the image.

Comment: Or just hide the image.

Comment: If Swing, use a JLabel, place the image into the label as an image icon, and then use a Swing Timer to remove the icon from the label after a delay. But whatever you do, do not repeatedly read in the image within some timer as that is a needless waste of resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in the else like below

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\mogen\\Pictures\\importImage\\explosion.gif");
if (elapsedTimeMsec >= 5200 && elapsedTimeMsec < 6100){

  g.drawImage(image, 750, 425, null);
}else{
  g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this before but I was given an error on "else" and couldn't figure out why. It turns out I had a semi-colon after if(), and seeing this code made me realize that mistake.